# How do I assign individual youtube images from an array to a div that is also dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, youtube-api

This block is dynamically being pulled in in Visual Basic.

```
foreach (Helper.Webinar webinar in ViewBag.Webinars){
<a href="@Url.Action("Webinars", "Learning", new { name = webinar.ContentFileName })" class="link-block">
    <div class="jumbotron left-right-jumbotron-block webinar-block">
    <div class="webinar-item-1"></div>
    <div class="webinar-item-2"></div>
    </div>
</a>
}
```

I'm trying to assign individual ID's tp the above using. As it stands, I can populate each of the above with the very last image in the array. I'm trying to figure out how to populate every block based on the number of ID's I have in the array.

```
const youtubeImgSort = () => {
const ids = [

    "", // leave blank
    "LJ3opnisLmk",
    "zTqLkVurK-A",
    "9PDexf_6HH0", 
    "wMmXGNmrr7I" 
];

$(".webinar-item-1").empty().append('<div class="vid-state"><img class="webThumb" alt="Webinar Preview Thumbnail"/></div>');

for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

    $('.webThumb').attr('src', 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + ids[i] + '/0.jpg').after('<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>');
    };

};

youtubeImgSort();
```

Comment: You should provide more info about what you've tried and what you are trying to accomplish to get good answers. You just pasted a bunch of code with little explanation. What does that code output? What were you expecting to see? I'm not sure what you mean by "that is also dynamic".

Comment: Hi, Ibrahim! I was able to get the very last image in the array to display, however, it displays the same image for each div, not a different image for each. I'm trying to to assign the images to a dynamic block:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what exactly your Visual Basic code is generating (is it looping and generating several `webinar-item-*`s?) and what needs to happen in Javascript.

Here is a demo where I moved the jQuery statement that fills the `webinar-item-*` into the loop and filled it with the correct image. I'm assuming that Visual basic is generating several HTML divs for the `webinar-item-*`s which may be incorrect. You could generate the `webinar-item-*`s in js but I'm not sure what the rest of your data looks like.

```js
const youtubeImgSort = () => {
  const ids = [

      "", // leave blank
      "LJ3opnisLmk",
      "zTqLkVurK-A",
      "9PDexf_6HH0", 
      "wMmXGNmrr7I" 
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
     $(".webinar-item-" + i)
       .empty()
       .append('<div class="vid-state"><img class="webThumb" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + ids[i] + '/0.jpg" alt="Webinar Preview Thumbnail" /><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>');
  }

};

youtubeImgSort();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webinar-item-0"></div>
<div class="webinar-item-1"></div>
<div class="webinar-item-2"></div>
<div class="webinar-item-3"></div>
<div class="webinar-item-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id based on the index and then use the jquery id selector to find the individual div element to append the youtube thumbnail.